# ImageView allow scale down, but not up

Tags: android, imageview, image-scaling

How could I make image scale down and fit ImageView, but avoid **up**scaling?

**Have solved** it with Glide, adding

```
...
.transform(new FitCenter(context) {
    @Override
    protected Bitmap transform(BitmapPool pool, Bitmap toTransform, int outWidth, int outHeight) {
        if (toTransform.getHeight() > outHeight || toTransform.getWidth() > outWidth)
            return super.transform(pool, toTransform, outWidth, outHeight);
        else
            return toTransform;
    }
})
...
```

and `android:scaleType="center"` in target `ImageView`.

It seems there is no way to get such a behavior using just `ImageView` attributes :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use Picasso library with the parameter `.onlyScaleDown()`

```
Picasso  
    .with(context)
    .load(imageURI)
    .resize(600, 800) // or better use fit()
    .onlyScaleDown() // the image will only be resized if it's bigger than 6000x2000 pixels.
    .into(imageViewResizeScaleDown);
```

https://futurestud.io/tutorials/picasso-image-resizing-scaling-and-fit

Comment: I use Glide, but would not like to use transforms.